# upload photo with resize in prosses error using php

Tags: php

I have error in this code:

```
  copy($newFile,$target_dir.'slider_'.$newName);
  $file2 = $target_dir.'slider_'.$newName; //This is the original file
  list($width2, $height2) = $newFile;

  $modwidth2 = 750;
  $modheight2 = 300;
  $tn2 = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth2, $modheight2);

  if ($imageFileType == "jpg"){

    $image2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($newFile);
    imagecopyresampled($tn2, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth2, $modheight2, $width2, $height2);
    imagejpeg($tn2, $file2, 50);

  } elseif  ($imageFileType == "png"){

    imagealphablending($tn2, false);
    imagesavealpha($tn2, true);
    $image2 = imagecreatefrompng($newFile);
    imagecopyresampled($tn2, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth2, $modheight2, $width2, $height2);
    imagepng($tn2, $file2, 9);

  } elseif  ($imageFileType == "jpeg"){

    $image2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($newFile);
    imagecopyresampled($tn2, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth2, $modheight2, $width2, $height2);
    imagejpeg($tn2, $file2, 9);

  }
```

If i upload a photo, output always blank black. Can u tell me what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: list($width2, $height2) = $newFile; what is this means ? it mighe be list($width2, $height2)  = getimagesize ($newFile)

Comment: get list width & height from $newfile, file its photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not getting width & height properly.

```
list($width2, $height2) = $newFile;
```

change to

```
list($width2, $height2) = getimagesize ($newFile)
```